# Fully qualifying IStream

Tags: c#, winforms

On my WinForm, a reference is created:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
```

When a variable is declared:

```
private IStream data;
```

This becomes a reference to the struct Namespace.

It must be fully qualified:

```
private System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream data;
```

What other reference could interfere with this?
I have another project that does not need to fully qualify this reference.

Comment: What: `This becomes a reference to the struct Namespace`? Also, does capitalizing `Data` make a difference?

Comment: Do you declare an `IStream` type or variable in your code?

Comment: If I create a property and fully qualify the private variable then do not qualify the public get/set, this error happens: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream' to 'IStream'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't fully qualify, do you get an ambiguous reference error? It should tell you what the two options are.. You can also use the refactoring helper -- if you do the dropdown to try and resolve it, it'll tell you where it's finding the interface..

Comment: Yes, the error is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream' to 'IStream'. And, the struct I was referring to is shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/istream%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Right so you have an IStream in the default namespace and one in ComTypes.. You'll have to be explicit unless you remove the ComTypes reference..